# Combining SQL grouped and ungrouped results with a cross join?

Tags: sql, subquery, filemaker

I have inherited two tables, where the data for one is in hours, and the data for the other is in days.

One table has planned resource use, the other holds actual hours spent

```
Internal_Resources

| PeopleName | NoOfDays | TaskNo |
|------------|----------|--------|
| Fred       |        1 |    100 |
| Bob        |        3 |    100 |
| Mary       |        2 |    201 |
| Albert     |       10 |    100 |


TimeSheetEntries

| UserName | PaidHours | TaskNumber |
|----------|-----------|------------|
| Fred     |         7 |        100 |
| Fred     |        14 |        100 |
| Fred     |         7 |        100 |
| Bob      |         7 |        100 |
| Bob      |        21 |        100 |
| Mary     |         7 |        201 |
| Mary     |        14 |        100 |
```

What I need is a comparison of time planned vs time spent.

```
| name   | PlannedDays | ActualDays |
|--------|-------------|------------|
| Albert |          10 |       NULL |
| Bob    |           3 |       4.00 |
| Fred   |           1 |       4.00 |
| Mary   |       NULL  |       2.00 |
```

I've cobbled together something that almost does the trick:

```
SELECT
    UserName, 
    ( SELECT
        NoOfDays FROM Internal_Resources as r
        WHERE r.PeopleName = e.UserName AND r.TaskNumber = ? ) AS PlannedDays,
    SUM ( Round( PaidHours / 7 , 2 ) ) as ActualDays
    FROM TimeSheetEntries e WHERE TaskNo = ? 
    GROUP BY UserName
```

Which for task 100 gives me back something like:

```
| UserName | PlannedDays | ActualDays |
|----------|-------------|------------|
| Bob      |           3 |          4 |
| Fred     |           1 |          4 |
| Mary     |           0 |          2 |
```

but lazy Albert doesn't feature! I'd like:

```
| UserName | PlannedDays | ActualDays |
|----------|-------------|------------|
| Albert   |          10 |          0 |
| Bob      |           3 |          4 |
| Fred     |           1 |          4 |
| Mary     |           0 |          2 |
```

I've tried using variations on

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ... ) AS plan
    INNER JOIN ( [second-query] ) AS actual
    ON plan.PeopleName = actual.UserName
```

What *should* I be doing? I suspect I need to squeeze a cross-join in there somewhere, but I'm getting nowhere...

( This going to be run inside a FileMaker ExecuteSQL() call, so I need pretty vanilla SQL... And no, I don't have control over the column or table names :-( )

EDIT:

To be clear, I need the result set to include both users who had planned days and haven't worked on a task, as well as those who have worked on a task without having planned days...

EDIT 2:

I can kind of get what I want manually, but can't see how to combine the statements below:

```
SELECT people.name, PlannedDays, ActualDays FROM
( SELECT PeopleName as name FROM Internal_Resources WHERE TaskNo = 100
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT UserName as name FROM TimeSheetEntries WHERE TaskNumber = 100 
ORDER BY Name) AS people
```

gets me:

```
+--------+
| name   |
+--------+
| Albert |
| Bob    |
| Fred   |
| Mary   |
+--------+
```

and:

```
( SELECT PeopleName AS name, NoOfDays AS PlannedDays
FROM Internal_Resources WHERE TaskNo = 100 ) AS actual
```

gets me:

```
+--------+-------------+
| name   | PlannedDays |
+--------+-------------+
| Fred   |           1 |
| Bob    |           3 |
| Albert |          10 |
+--------+-------------+
```

and finally,

```
( SELECT UserName AS name, SUM( Round( PaidHours / 7, 2 ) ) AS ActualDays
FROM TimeSheetEntries
WHERE TaskNumber = 100 GROUP BY UserName ) AS planned
```

gets me:

```
+------+------------+
| name | ActualDays |
+------+------------+
| Bob  |       4.00 |
| Fred |       4.00 |
| Mary |       2.00 |
+------+------------+
```

Now all (All! ha!) I want is to combine these into this:

```
+--------+-------------+------------+
| name   | PlannedDays | ActualDays |
+--------+-------------+------------+
| Albert |          10 |       NULL |
| Bob    |           3 |       4.00 |
| Fred   |           1 |       4.00 |
| Mary   |       NULL  |       2.00 |
+--------+-------------+------------+
```

EDIT 3:

I've tried combining it with something along the lines of:

```
SELECT people.name, PlannedDays, ActualDays
FROM ( SELECT PeopleName as name FROM Internal_Resources WHERE TaskNo = 100
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT UserName as name FROM TimeSheetEntries WHERE TaskNumber = 100 
  ORDER BY Name) AS people

LEFT JOIN ( SELECT PeopleName AS name, NoOfDays AS PlannedDays FROM Internal_Resources WHERE TaskNo = 100 ) AS actual, 
ON people.name = actual.name

LEFT JOIN ( SELECT UserName AS name, SUM( Round( PaidHours / 7, 2 ) ) AS ActualDays FROM TimeSheetEntries WHERE TaskNumber = 100 GROUP BY UserName ) AS planned
ON people.name = planned.name;
```

but the syntax is clearly wonky.

Comment: I don't think cross join is supported in FileMaker

Comment: No - it does for FileMaker tables via the define relationship dialog, but no, via ExecuteSQL, it doesn't directly. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay - this works:

```
SELECT people.name, COALESCE(PlannedDays, 0) as planned, COALESCE(ActualDays, 0) as actual
FROM ( SELECT PeopleName as name FROM Internal_Resources WHERE TaskNo = 100
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT UserName as name FROM TimeSheetEntries WHERE TaskNumber = 100 
  ORDER BY Name) AS people

LEFT JOIN ( SELECT PeopleName AS name, NoOfDays AS PlannedDays FROM Internal_Resources WHERE TaskNo = 100 ) AS ir 
ON people.name = ir.name

LEFT JOIN ( SELECT UserName AS name, SUM( Round( PaidHours / 7, 2 ) ) AS ActualDays FROM TimeSheetEntries WHERE TaskNumber = 100 GROUP BY UserName ) AS ts
ON people.name = ts.name;
```

Giving:

```
+--------+---------+--------+
| name   | planned | actual |
+--------+---------+--------+
| Albert |      10 |   0.00 |
| Bob    |       3 |   4.00 |
| Fred   |       1 |   4.00 |
| Mary   |       0 |   2.00 |
+--------+---------+--------+
```

I thought there must be an easier way, and this looks simpler:

```
SELECT name, SUM(x) AS planned, SUM(y) AS actual 
FROM (

  SELECT PeopleName AS name, NoOfDays AS x, 0 AS y
  FROM Internal_Resources WHERE TaskNo = 100

  UNION

  SELECT UserName AS name, 0 AS x, SUM( PaidHours / 7 ) AS y
  FROM TimeSheetEntries WHERE TaskNumber = 100 GROUP BY UserName) AS source

GROUP BY name;
```

But frustratingly - both work in MySQL and both FAIL in FileMaker's cut-down SQL version - SELECTing from a derived table doesn't appear to be supported.

Finally - the trick to getting it to work in FileMaker SQL - subqueries are supported for IN and NOT IN... so a union of three queries - people who have planned days and have done some work, people who have done unplanned work, and people who haven't done planned work:

```
SELECT PeopleName as name, NoOfDays as planned, Sum( PaidHours / 7 ) as actual 
    FROM Internal_Resources 
    JOIN TimeSheetEntries 
    ON PeopleName = UserName 
    WHERE TaskNumber = 100 AND TaskNo = 100 GROUP BY PeopleName

UNION

SELECT UserName as name, 0 as planned, Sum( PaidHours / 7 ) as actual
    FROM TimeSheetEntries 
    WHERE TaskNumber = 100 
    AND UserName NOT IN (
        SELECT PeopleName FROM Internal_Resources WHERE TaskNo = 100
    )

UNION

SELECT PeopleName as name, NoOfDays as planned, 0 as actual 
    FROM Internal_Resources WHERE TaskNo = 100
    AND PeopleName NOT IN (
        SELECT PeopleName as name
        FROM Internal_Resources JOIN TimeSheetEntries 
        ON PeopleName = UserName 
        WHERE TaskNumber = 100 AND TaskNo =  100 
        GROUP BY PeopleName
    )

ORDER BY name;
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Invert the logic to read from `Internal_resources` in the outer query:

```
SELECT ir.UserName, NoOfDays as PlannedDays,
       (SELECT SUM ( Round( PaidHours / 7 , 2 ))
        FROM TimeSheetEntries e
        WHERE e.TaskNo = ? AND ir.PeopleName = e.UserName
       ) as ActualDays
FROM Internal_Resources ir
WHERE ir.TaskNumber = ?
GROUP BY ir.UserName, NoOfDays;
```

Comment: Nope, sorry. First, the GROUP BY breaks, due to non-aggregates in the SELECT list, and second, without the group by, I only get those people who have planned days, and not those sneaky buggers who have worked on a task without planned days.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't filemaker support LEFT OUTER JOINs?

```
SELECT
    PeopleName,
    NoOfDays AS PlannedDays
    ROUND(SUM(PaidHours) / 7, 2) AS ActualDays
FROM
    Internal_Resources AS planned
-- left join should not discard Albert's record from Internal_Resources
LEFT JOIN TimeSheetEntries AS actual
    ON planned.PeopleName = actual.UserName
    AND planned.TaskNo = actual.TaskNumber
WHERE
    planned.TaskNo = ?
GROUP BY PeopleName, NoOfDays
```

Comment: Err - nope. Even testing it in MySQL only gives a partial answer... Result set DOESN'T include poor old Mary, who definitely did 2 days work.